Can't find specific table in Wikipedia with Webscraping?
I am scraping the following wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022.
I was able to scrape another table from this page already, but now I want to scrape the 'Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022' table. However, I can't seem to find the table.
This is my code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table2_2022 = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders")
semifinal1_2022 = table_2022[2]

The complete class name in the html code has jquery-tablesorter after it, but based on other similar questions, I dropped that.
I used find_all because there are multiple tables in the Wikipedia page. The problem is that I can't seem to get the table I want. If I select the table table_2022[2], I get the table before the one I want (with the various pots), and when I choose table_2022[3], I get the 'Detailed jury voting results of semi-final 1', which is the first table after the one I want which has 'wikitable plainheaders' as class. There are a couple of tables in between the pots table and the 'Detailed jury voting results of semi-final 1', but I can't seem to access any of them.
I have also tried to find the table using a caption search as follows:
tables = soup.find_all('table')

desired_caption = "Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022"

desired_table = None
for table in tables:
    caption = table.find('caption')
    if caption and caption.text.strip() == desired_caption:
        desired_table = table
        break

# If the desired table is found, scrape it
if desired_table:
    # Do your scraping logic here
    pass
else:
    print("Desired table not found.")

But here I get the result 'Desired table not found.'

Your first approach
I'm not sure I understood your reasoning. The results you've described couldn't have come from the query that you have posted.
I've edited your code and observed that the result you seek is the first entry in table_2022:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table_2022 = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders")
semifinal1_2022 = table_2022[0]
print(semifinal1_2022.find('caption').text.strip())
# prints: Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022[149]

Your second approach
You're querying for caption with text entry:
"Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022"
but the actual table has the following caption text:
"Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022[149]"

You could either look for a different exact match:
desired_caption = "Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022[149]"

or keep the old one and check if it's contained in the actual one:
desired_caption = "Participants and results of the first semi-final of the Eurovision Song Contest 2022"
# ...
if caption and desired_caption in caption.text.strip():
    desired_table = table
    break

